# How to modify Keras Siamese Network example?

Tags: keras

I've tried to change code from [Keras example about siamese network](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese_graph.py). But the weird thing is that the accuracy is always be 0.5000, regardless of the loss decrement. My hypothesis for now is that i was wrongly modify the `create_pair` function, i wanna try to change the number of classes into 4:

Original:

```
def create_pairs(x, digit_indices):
'''Positive and negative pair creation.
Alternates between positive and negative pairs.
'''
pairs = []
labels = []
n = min([len(digit_indices[d]) for d in range(10)]) - 1
for d in range(10):
    for i in range(n):
        z1, z2 = digit_indices[d][i], digit_indices[d][i + 1]
        pairs += [[x[z1], x[z2]]]
        inc = random.randrange(1, 10)
        dn = (d + inc) % 10
        z1, z2 = digit_indices[d][i], digit_indices[dn][i]
        pairs += [[x[z1], x[z2]]]
        labels += [1, 0]
return np.array(pairs), np.array(labels)
```

and, in line 93-97:

```
digit_indices = [np.where(y_train == i)[0] for i in range(10)]
tr_pairs, tr_y = create_pairs(x_train, digit_indices)

digit_indices = [np.where(y_test == i)[0] for i in range(10)]
te_pairs, te_y = create_pairs(x_test, digit_indices)
```

This is my code :

```
def create_pairs(x, digit_indices):
'''Positive and negative pair creation.
Alternates between positive and negative pairs.
'''
pairs = []
labels = []
n = min([len(digit_indices[d]) for d in range(4)]) - 1
for d in range(4):
    for i in range(n):
        z1, z2 = digit_indices[d][i], digit_indices[d][i + 1]
        pairs += [[x[z1], x[z2]]]
        inc = random.randrange(1, 4)
        dn = (d + inc) % 4
        z1, z2 = digit_indices[d][i], digit_indices[dn][i]
        pairs += [[x[z1], x[z2]]]
        labels += [1, 0]
return np.array(pairs), np.array(labels)
```

and, in line 93-97:

```
digit_indices = [np.where(y_train == i)[0] for i in range(4)]
tr_pairs, tr_y = create_pairs(x_train, digit_indices)

digit_indices = [np.where(y_test == i)[0] for i in range(4)]
te_pairs, te_y = create_pairs(x_test, digit_indices)
```

And here's my base_network (the one that use RNN, not the conv net i've talked about in the comment reply, both give the same result, 50% of accuracy):

```
def create_base_network(embedding_layer):
    seq = Sequential()
    seq.add(embedding_layer)
    seq.add(GRU(512, use_bias=True, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5, return_sequences=True))
    seq.add(GRU(512, use_bias=True, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
    seq.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    seq.add(Dropout(0.1))
    seq.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    return seq
```

The embedding layer is just a simple glove matrix. And i also add another dense layer using sigmoid activation function after the merging.

Anything missing? Or that is not how i should change it? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm getting `* Accuracy on training set: 99.97%`` * Accuracy on test set: 99.69%` for 0 to 3 digits... what else did you change?

Comment: you can view here my changes for limit you were asking https://gist.github.com/oak-tree/49fcbee1d2ecfb11c78b1b64bafc9a76

Comment: i change the base_network too, i tried to replicate [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rsalakhu/papers/oneshot1.pdf). So i changed the base network using conv net(s) and add a dense layer after the lambda layer + i change the euclidean distance into L1 distance. So i guess probably i just need to increase the epoch so that the conv layer can learn more (?). What do you think?

Comment: If you post your source It be easier to help. note by the paper you added you also need to add sigmoid activition

Comment: Yes i've added the sigmoid layer after the Lambda layer, and i've update the question to show you my base_network, any suggestion for that code? @oak

Comment: Maybe too much dropout? Anyhow, in the paper you mention the authors do `conv` . I would try first to see if the network converges using their architecture. After you succeed try to play with the architecture like you

Comment: I've tried the conv layer, and then changed the loss function and labels like the answer given by emanuele below(which is the same with the paper), It gives a bad result. But if i use the same loss function and labels like in the keras example it gives a good result. I'm afraid that it is a false positive. What do you think @oak?

Comment: As for the @emanuele fix and your current version:  What you want is `double` the distance if the pairs are equal - this is the loss for pairs should be be with "zero" distance. But if the pairs are distinct from each other you want to calculate their distance from the margin and double it. This what you need to verify at the version that you are running.

Comment: double the distance or divide the distance by 2 just like the loss function in the original paper? what version do i need to verify? and how to verify it?

Answer (score 0):

The Siamese code is wrong and not yet fixed. The problem is the loss function that is not symmetric in switching 0 and 1, but the keras code assume that it is.
Change this line

```
return K.mean(y_true * K.square(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0)))
```

into

```
return K.mean((1 - y_true) * K.square(y_pred) + y_true * K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0)))
```

and

```
labels += [1, 0]
```

into

```
labels += [0, 1]
```

Comment: But, i've tried the original code and it shows a good result, and then i tried to change the data, still giving (sort of) a good result. But when i changed the base_network into a one layer convolution then the accuracy will stuck at 50%

Comment: I've tried to change the loss function and labels just like what you said. But it gave even worse result. But when i use the code given by keras. It shows a great result. Is it possible that it is a false positive experiment?

Comment: It is possible that you have a newer version of keras, and the bug in the original code has been fixed. But in any case your code cannot be worst than 50% because is the baseline of pure chance. This means that there is a bug, somewhere, in your code.

Comment: So do you think that i should just use the code given by the keras in mnist_siamese_graph.py eventhough it is not using the same contrastive loss equation like in the original paper? Cause i would be happy to do so since it gives me a really great result @emanuele

Comment: No, I am just telling the there is a bug somewhere in you code.

Comment: How to check which version that i used?

Comment: ```import keras;
print keras.__version__```

Comment: i use keras 2.0.0 . Is it possible that if i use the contrastive loss function given by the keras example, i will get the correct result?